# Polynomial with an integer root

Tags: polynomials

is it possible to determine a positive integers 'a' and 'b'

$$ x^b  -a -1 =0 $$

so at least ONE of its root is a positive integer ?

for example for $ a=b=2 $ we get $ x =2 $

but are there another examples

how about i 'a' and 'b' can be negative integers ?

Comment: For $a=b=2$ we have $x^2=3$.  Maybe there is a typo in your equation?

Comment: As written, the roots are $b$-th roots of $a+1$ (so we just check if there is an integer root here). If you mean $x^b-ax-1=0$, then use the rational roots theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $a$ and $b$ to be positive, there are many choices. Here are just some examples: $(a,b,x)\in\{(3,2,2),(8,2,3),(7,3,2)\}$.

There are no positive integer solutions $x$ in case $a$ is negative. If there were, then $$x^b=a+1$$ gives a positive number on the LHS, but a non-positive number on the RHS; contradiction.